# Fine-tuning a pre-trained Tensorflow model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I have two questions regarding fine-tuning a pre-trained Tensorflow model on a mix of high-quality and low-quality images.In other words, '

1. Does the large contrast in image quality confuses the model learning process ? Is it better to have more than one name (label) for the same class such as low-quality_cat, high-quality_cat, etc. I mean while labelling the dataset.
2. If I fine-tune the Tensorflow model on the data, say 300 images per class, then later I want to increment the number of images (say the exact same 300 images + 200 more images) and classes, do I fine-tune the original pre-defined Tensorflow model each time or the model exported from My last training ?